# Type Check help on Object with string index

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have two objects that I would like to share similar keys that I can reference via string.  All I want them to share is the keys, and I'd like to verify that no one can add any other keys via a type check.

So I've tried the following, but I am getting stuck on setting the options.

Or if there is a better way of doing this (I'm sure this is), I'd be happy to hear it.

So essentially, I'd like to ensure that options only contains specific values for each individual dropdown. When the dropdown gets selected, I'd like to update the property of another object based on the current key.

```
export interface Dropdown{
    label: string;
    disabled?: boolean;
    options: { [key: string]: Option};
}

export interface Option{
    label: string;
    selected?: boolean;
    value?: string;
    disabled?: boolean;
}

declare type DropdownTypes= "city" | "state";
declare type color= "blue" | "red";
declare type number= "1" | "2";

export type DropDowns= {
    [key in DropdownTypes]: Dropdown;
};
```

I'd like to be able to do:

`Object.keys(s as DropDowns).forEach((k: string) => { const item = s[k];   })`

But `get Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type`

Comment: Could you please provide some example of expected code? I don't see any errors in your code. It is hard to understand what are you expect, at least for me

Comment: I'd like to be able to do: 

```Object.keys(s as DropDowns).forEach((k: string) => { const item = s[k];   })```

But ```get Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Object.keys` returns always `string[]` therefore you will need the casting.

```
const keys = Object.keys(s) as DropdownTypes[];
keys.forEach(k => { const item = s[k];   })
```

Answer (score 0):

Just also had to add

```
Object.keys(s as DropDowns).forEach((k: string) => { const item = s[k as DropdownTypes];   })
```

Comment: I would prefer answer of @Zoltan. The type casting should be done early. The `keys` may be used somewhere else too. Type casting each time while iterating is not so good idea.

Comment: Moreover, firstly you are saying `k` is string explicitly and then `DropdownTypes`.